# Example of how to use Omniauth with Azure B2C and OpenID Connect

Tags: openid-connect, omniauth, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to use Omniauth to initiate an implicit flow login to Azure B2C.

I found the following example from https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth_openid_connect. But, I will change it like below to use implicit flow.

```
config.omniauth :openid_connect, {
  name: :my_provider,
  scope: [:openid],
  response_type: :id_token,
  uid_field: "preferred_username",
  client_options: {
    port: 443,
    scheme: "https",
    host: "myprovider.com",
    identifier: ENV["OP_CLIENT_ID"],
    redirect_uri: "http://myapp.com/users/auth/openid_connect/callback",
  },
}
```

However, I need to configure this for Azure B2C, which includes a specific authorization endpoint and policy name. I see that I can specify a `host` which appears to probably just be a domain name. And I can also specify a path to `authorization_endpoint`.

Considering that the Azure B2C authorization endpoint is:
`https://<tenant name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`
And I can specify as a parameter `p=<policy ID>`. Or,
`https://<tenant name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/<Policy ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` without the `p=<Policy ID>` parameter.

How would the Omniauth client be configured to do this?

Would I just specify the `host` as `<tenant name>.b2clogin.com` and specify the `authorization_endpoint` as `/<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/<Policy ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`?

What about the the discovery endpoint which is supposed to automatically handle configuring the `authorization_endpoint` and other options?